# Complex if statements in authentication method

Tags: php, optimization, object-oriented, php5, authentication

I had asked questions about my entire class which I'll flag for closing soon. It appeared to be a little too broad for 1 post so I chopped it up and will be asking a little more specific questions separately.

---

In my Application Layer I have a class `AuthService` containing the following method with a code structure that has gotten quite complex with if statements that I'm unable to re-factor a better way.

I'd appreciate anybody who could review this piece of code and give me suggestions on  improving / optimizing the design of it. Any other suggestions are welcome as well.

```
public function findLoggedInUser()
{
    if (($userData = $this->httpSession->getParameter('user')) && isset($userData['id'])) {
        // User found in current http session
        return $this->userMapper->findById($userData['id']);
    } elseif ($httpSessionData = $this->httpCookie->getParameter('usess')) {
        if (isset($httpSessionData['uid'], $httpSessionData['sno'], $httpSessionData['token'])) {
            if ($user = $this->userMapper->findById($httpSessionData['uid'])) {
                if ($httpSession = $this->httpSessionMapper->findByUserAndSeriesNo($user, $httpSessionData['sno'])) {
                    if (password_verify($httpSessionData['token'], (string) $httpSession->getTokenHash()) {
                        // Generate new http session entity tokens
                        $token['raw']  = new Token(CryptoCharGen::numeric(60));
                        $token['hash'] = new TokenHash(password_hash((string) $token['raw'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 4]));

                        // Update and persist http session entity with new token
                        $httpSession->setTokenHash($token['hash']);

                        $this->httpSessionMapper->update($httpSession);

                        // Issue new http cookie usess with updated http session recovery data
                        $this->httpCookie->setParameter('usess', [
                            'uid'   => (string) $httpSession->getUser()->getId(),
                            'sno'   => (string) $httpSession->getSeriesNo(),
                            'token' => (string) $token['raw']
                        ], 60 * 60 * 24 * 90);

                        // User has been found
                        return $httpSession->getUser();
                    } else {
                        // Token invalid, sabotage assumed
                        // Invalidate all persisted http sessions of this user
                        $this->httpSessionMapper->deleteAllByUser($user);

                        $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
                    }
                } else {
                    // Destroy invalid cookie
                    $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
                }
            } else {
                // Destroy invalid cookie
                $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
            }
        } else {
            // Destroy invalid cookie
            $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is returned if either main `if` or `elseif` conditions aren't met?

Comment: @shudder Nothing (`null`).

Comment: I have to say that it's hard for me to refactor this because while I see some design flaws I can't see the context (don't want to guess). I suggest you to split this method into more smaller ones (do one thing only & mind [Command-Query Separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation)). Some other flaws should reveal themselves. This movie was usefull for me on this matter, so you might check it out: [Your code sucks, let's fix it!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H2AvoAzbGOE).

Comment: @shudder Very helpful video regarding maintainable and modulair code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Use Guard Expressions

The proper way to do this is to use [Guard expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guard_(computer_science)).

If you have a number of conditions that need to be true before you take an action. You don't check them all in a nested manner but instead check their negations one and one and return/break if you find any condition that is not met.

### Example

Instead of having:

```
if(a){
  if(b){
    if(c)
      ...
      return SUCCESS;
    else
      return FAIL;
  else
    return FAIL;
}
else
  return FAIL;
```

You can invert the checks and collapse the nesting like this:

```
if(!a)
   return FAIL;
if(!b)
   return FAIL;
if(!c)
   return FAIL
...
return SUCCESS;
```

Or if the consequence of failing the checks are the same, you can collapse the ifs like this:

```
if(!a || !b || !c)
   return FAIL;
...
return SUCCESS;
```

Which method to choose depends on how long the expressions `a`, `b` and `c` are and which one you find more readable.

### Your code

Use with caution! I might have missed something as my PHP is rusty.

```
if (!isset($httpSessionData['uid'], $httpSessionData['sno'], $httpSessionData['token'])) {
   $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
   return;
}
$user = $this->userMapper->findById($httpSessionData['uid'])
if (!$user) {
    $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
   return;
}

$httpSession = $this->httpSessionMapper->findByUserAndSeriesNo($user, $httpSessionData['sno'])
if (!$httpSession) {
    $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
   return;
}

if (password_verify($httpSessionData['token'], (string) $httpSession->getTokenHash()) {
    // ...
    return $httpSession->getUser();
} else {
    // Token invalid, sabotage assumed
    // Invalidate all persisted http sessions of this user
    $this->httpSessionMapper->deleteAllByUser($user);
    $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
}
```

Comment: Am I correct that this is the same expression strategy as in George's answer? And I appreciate your constructive answer.

Comment: Yeah, we wrote our answers simultaneously and I didn't see theirs. :s

Comment: It's okay. You did it just a little more thoroughly, which is always helpful. :)

Comment: A note about the example code, I would recommend a `terminateSession()` function and call it instead of `httpCookie->destroy(...)`. You know, to help with DRY. :)

Answer (score 7):

Two suggestions on how to keep this code maintainable:

- use [early exits](http://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#use-early-exits-and-continue-to-simplify-code)
- keep conditions atomic (one `if` checks for one thing)

Example:

```
function findLoggedInUser()
{
    if (($userData = $this->httpSession->getParameter('user')) && isset($userData['id'])) {
        // User found in current http session
        return $this->userMapper->findById($userData['id']);
    }

    $httpSessionData = $this->httpCookie->getParameter('usess');
    if(!$httpSessionData) {
        $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
        return null;
    }

    if(!isset($httpSessionData['uid'], $httpSessionData['sno'], $httpSessionData['token'])) {
        $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
        return null;
    }

    $user = $this->userMapper->findById($httpSessionData['uid']);
    if(!$user) {
        $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
        return null;
    }

    $httpSession = $this->httpSessionMapper->findByUserAndSeriesNo($user, $httpSessionData['sno']));
    if(!$httpSessionData) {
        $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
        return null;
    }

    if (!password_verify($httpSessionData['token'], (string) $httpSession->getTokenHash()) {
        $this->httpSessionMapper->deleteAllByUser($user);
        $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
        return null;
    }

    // EVERYTHING'S FINE, DO THE JOB

    // Generate new http session entity tokens
    $token['raw']  = new Token(CryptoCharGen::numeric(60));
    $token['hash'] = new TokenHash(password_hash((string) $token['raw'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 4]));

    // Update and persist http session entity with new token
    $httpSession->setTokenHash($token['hash']);

    $this->httpSessionMapper->update($httpSession);

    // Issue new http cookie usess with updated http session recovery data
    $this->httpCookie->setParameter('usess', [
        'uid'   => (string) $httpSession->getUser()->getId(),
    'sno'   => (string) $httpSession->getSeriesNo(),
    'token' => (string) $token['raw']
        ], 60 * 60 * 24 * 90);

    // User has been found
    return $httpSession->getUser();
}
```

This way, the code remains readable and flexible for future modifications.

Answer (score 3):

In the deeply nested code, ultimately you either return a user, or else destroy the `usess` cookie if something fails at any point. So instead of this:

> ```
> if (isset($httpSessionData['uid'], $httpSessionData['sno'], $httpSessionData['token'])) {
>     if ($user = $this->userMapper->findById($httpSessionData['uid'])) {
>         if ($httpSession = $this->httpSessionMapper->findByUserAndSeriesNo($user, $httpSessionData['sno'])) {
>             if (password_verify($httpSessionData['token'], (string) $httpSession->getTokenHash()) {
>                 // ...
>
>                 return $httpSession->getUser();
>             } else {
>                 // Token invalid, sabotage assumed
>                 // Invalidate all persisted http sessions of this user
>                 $this->httpSessionMapper->deleteAllByUser($user);
>
>                 $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
>             }
>         } else {
>             // Destroy invalid cookie
>             $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
>         }
>     } else {
>         // Destroy invalid cookie
>         $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
>     }
> } else {
>     // Destroy invalid cookie
>     $this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
> }
> ```

You could do like this:

```
if (isset($httpSessionData['uid'], $httpSessionData['sno'], $httpSessionData['token'])) {
    if ($user = $this->userMapper->findById($httpSessionData['uid'])) {
        if ($httpSession = $this->httpSessionMapper->findByUserAndSeriesNo($user, $httpSessionData['sno'])) {
            if (password_verify($httpSessionData['token'], (string) $httpSession->getTokenHash()) {
                // ...

                return $httpSession->getUser();
            }
            // Token invalid, sabotage assumed
            // Invalidate all persisted http sessions of this user
            $this->httpSessionMapper->deleteAllByUser($user);
        }
    }
}
// Destroy invalid cookie
$this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
```

And instead of such deeply nested `if`, it might be more readable to chain conditions together with `&&`:

```
// note: remember to use if (($x = val) && ...) { ... }
//       instead of just if ($x = val && ...) { ... }
if (isset($httpSessionData['uid'], $httpSessionData['sno'], $httpSessionData['token'])
    && ($user = $this->userMapper->findById($httpSessionData['uid']))
    && ($httpSession = $this->httpSessionMapper->findByUserAndSeriesNo($user, $httpSessionData['sno']))) {

    if (password_verify($httpSessionData['token'], (string) $httpSession->getTokenHash()) {
        // ...

        return $httpSession->getUser();
    }
    // Token invalid, sabotage assumed
    // Invalidate all persisted http sessions of this user
    $this->httpSessionMapper->deleteAllByUser($user);
}
// Destroy invalid cookie
$this->httpCookie->destroy('usess');
```

Comment: Would it be possible to have those 3 chained expressions in that if statement stored in an array `$expressions` and use `!in_array(false, $expressions)` as the expression for the if statement for better readability?

Comment: Probably it's possible, but I don't think it would help readability. There is a "sweet spot" where it's good to stop trying to optimize.

Comment: Yeah, but I think readability preferences are probably different for everyone. I'm the only one that has to read this code later again. :P

Comment: You never know. You see, I'm reading your code *right now*. Another problem with `in_array` is that it would evaluate all expressions, but with `a && b` if `a` is false then `b` should not be evaluated. Maybe you can find another solution instead of `in_array`, but I think it's going to be hack-ish, obscure. Also remember Occam's Razor: the simple solutions are often better

Comment: Good points. I'll just stick with your solution, unless somebody else has a better idea.